# Table Value Parameter ReadOnly Work-Around

Tags: sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

I have a SProc with a Table-valued Parameter, `@section` of type `dbo.SectionIn`.  This param is being used throughout the SProc and I would like to remove some records from it but of course it is ReadOnly by design.

```
The table-valued parameter "@sections" is READONLY and cannot be modified.
```

My plan is to copy its contents into a table variable and use it instead.

```
DECLARE @sectionDups as dbo.SectionIn
    INSERT INTO @sectionDups
    SELECT *
    FROM @sections
```

My question is will this incur any performance hit in the Query plan and if not, what's the reasoning behind the ReadOnly requirement in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

There will be performance hit because of copying the table, the more rows in param table, the more it hurts performance, but if it can be negligible to the total run of sp

AFAIK the only reason of readonly tvp is - because it is very fresh feature in sql server and read-write is still under construction, so - be patient

Answer (score 0):

You should not copy the TVP table variable to a new table variable. If you want to exclude rows then do one of the following:

1. Use a `WHERE` clause to filter out unwanted rows.

   or
2. Create a local temporary table (single `#`) and copy the TVP data to that. Although doing so would seem to require using a WHERE clause, so this doesn't have a lot of value outside of:

   - better statistics for a temp table as opposed to table variable (but using statement level `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` solves that one)
   - ability to add columns
   - ability to modify values already in the TVP